# Is there a numerical measure of diagonalizability for matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Is there an effectively computable function $f$ from matrices to numbers such that $f(M)$ is nonzero if and only if $M$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: $f(A) = AA^*-A^*A$ is zero for diagonalizable matrices. This can be composed with function that gives $1$ for zero matrix and $0$ for other matrices. But I am not sure if this is either effectively computable or what you had in mind.

Comment: @Korf Not all diagonalizable matrices are normal

Comment: For example$$\begin{pmatrix}a&a-b\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$$has eigenvalues $a$ and $b$ but it is normal only when $a=b$.

Comment: Oh, I messed up diagonalizable and unitary diagonalizable. Sorry and thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$, then its minimal polynomial $p_A$ is effectively computable (eventually using a software with complexity $O(n^3)$) and the following non-continuous function $f$ is s.t. $f(A)=0$ iff $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.

$f:A\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow gcd(p_A(x),{p_A}'(x))-1$.

EDIT 3. Remark 1. We may replace $\mathbb{Q}$ with a finite algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand, if the $(a_{i,j})$ are not exactly known and if some eigenvalues are very closed, then we cannot conclude with regard to the diagonalisability of $A$; this comes mainly from the non-continuity of $f$.

Remark 2. The set $Z$ of non-diagonalizable complex matrices is a Zariski close set; then it has zero measure and its interior is void. For example, if you randomly choose a matrix in $M_{10}([[-100,100]])$, then it is "always" diagonalizable (because it has distinct eigenvalues).

Thus, you are right; it is natural to construct a function $g$ that is $0$ exactly on $Z$ rather than a function $f$ that is $\not= 0$ exactly on $Z$. We choose such a function $g$ as follows:

Let $sign(u)=1,0,-1$ when $u>0,u=0,u<0$. Then put $g(A)=sign(|discrim(p_A)|)$ where $discrim(.)$ is the discriminant.

If $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, then $discrim(p_A)\not= 0$ and $g(A)=1$. If $A$ is not, then $discrim(p_A)=0$ and $g(A)=0$.

Comment: Nice! Another answer also provides an example of this discontinuity: for $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&t\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, your $f(A)$ is $\gcd(x^2,2x)-1=(2?)x-1$ when $t\ne0$ and $\gcd(x,1)-1=0$ when $t=0$. Note however that the request was for $f(A)=0$ if and only if $A$ is *not* diagonalizable; how about that?

Comment: Remark 2: yes, yes, this is exactly what I want - a function that is 0 exactly on non-diagonalizable matrices, this is what I ask in the question! Can you give a natural such function?

Comment: Remark 1: well, there also exist diagonalizable matrices with coinciding eigenvalues

Comment: Sorry I don't understand now. Both your $f$ and $g$ are zero on diagonalizable matrices, aren't they?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე . If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $discrim(p_A)\not= 0$ and $g(A)=0$. If $A$ is not, then $discrim(p_A)=0$ and $g(A)=-1$.

Comment: Yes, I agree. And for your $f$, if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $f(A)=0$ too. And if $A$ is not, then $f(A)\ne0$. So your $f$ and $g$ do more or less the same thing, and it is opposite to what was asked in the question. The question was whether there is a function $f$ such that if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $f(A)\ne0$, while if $A$ is not, then $f(A)=0$.

Comment: For example, on $2\times2$-matrices such a function is$$|\operatorname{Trace}(A)^2-4\operatorname{Determinant}(A)|+(1-\operatorname{Sign}|A_{12}|)(1-\operatorname{Sign}|A_{21}|)$$

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე . I wrote too fast. cf. my edit

Comment: OK thanks. In fact you could also write simply $g(A)=\operatorname{Discriminant}(p_A)$. The problem is that the minimal polynomial is easily calculated for numerical matrices, but for symbolic matrices I am not aware of any expressions without things like "if blablabla then blabla else blablabla"...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this answers your question. If not, I will delete it.

There is no continuous functions $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $f(M)\neq0$ if and only if $f$ is diagonalizable. I will prove it when $n=2$, but the general case is similar. If there was such a function, we would have$$(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}):f\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&t\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)=0.$$But then$$f\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)=\lim_{t\to0}f\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&t\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)=0,$$which cannot happen, since $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ *is* diagonalisable.

Comment: I would say this is a very heavy evidence that the answer is most likely negative. Let me add that even if we agree that the zero matrix is *not* diagonalizable, continuity cannot be saved since the zero matrix is also a limit of nonzero diagonal matrices...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't think the we will ever agree that the null matrix is not diagonalisable. After all, it is a *diagonal* matrix.

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე  ; the zero matrix is not diagonalizable! what an extraordinary scoop! Do you have other revelations  ?

Comment: @loupblanc (1) I said 'even if' :P (2) there might be some considerations in favour of this, like non-diagonalizable means degenerate in some sense, and the zero matrix is as degenerate as it ever gets; (3) thanks for the answer!

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე . For (1), it was a joke.